# How to properly add a library to a c project in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c, visual-studio, linker, libraries

I'm trying to compile a program that includes libraries of 2 different SDKs.

I've added a bit of processing to a pre-compiled c example (AsychronousGrab) of the VimbaC SDK (an SDK to control and capture images of specific cameras).

Then, I decided I wanted to add to that code another SDK, the TRISciLib (used to control an autocollimator, basically a sensor that measures inclinations of optical surfaces).

So, I've started by adding all the header files used in the TRISciLib example to the header files folder of the Vimba example.

Here you can see them in the folder with this path:
`C:\Users\...\Tip-Tilt\VimbaC_Examples\AsynchronousGrab\Source`
[image: Header files folder]

It's the same path that has both .c files from the AsynchronoysGrab example of Vimba as you can see (`AsynchronousGrab.c` and `program.c`)

Then I added them to the file tree, on header files -> add existing item
[image: Header files tree]

Then, of course, in the main .c, the `program.c` I've included the main header:
`#include <SCIPrismMaster.h>`

Then, after a bit of searching here on StackOverflow, I've found out how to add a library. So, I went to project -> properties -> linker -> general and added to *Additional Library Directories* the following:
`$(VIMBA_HOME)\VimbaImageTransform\Lib\Win$(PlatformArchitecture);C:\Users\...\Tip-Tilt\VimbaC_Examples\Common;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)`

That path is where I've added the `TRISciLib.lib`:
[image: TRISciLib directory]

Just to clarify, the other `.lib`, the `Vimba.lib`, that is working and came pre-compiled by the SDK provider is on `C:\Users\...\Tip-Tilt\VimbaC_Examples\Common\VimbaC\Lib\Win64`

Finally, I went to project -> properties -> linker -> input and added to *Additional Dependencies* the `TRISciLib.lib`:
`VimbaC.lib;VimbaImageTransform.lib;TRISciLib.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

After concluding this process, I've copied basically the whole example provided by the TRISciLib SDK into the `program.c` from the Vimba SDK. And when I try to build I get a bunch of linker errors:
[image: linker errors]

So, what am I doing wrong here?